# Python tkinter - radio buttons, how to change outcome according to user selection multiple times?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, anaconda, radio-button

So in my code I have a menu of radio buttons. I've assigned them to display a string of text depending on what radio button is selected. However, how can I make it dynamic to where, if the user changes their mind after selecting one option, the outcome changes?
For example, let's say my menu options are:
-blue
-red
-yellow

User selects blue. Then the text "blue" displays as an outcome of that selection. But now, the user changes their selection to red instead. If they now click on the "red" option from the menu, how can I sort of undo the previous text and display the new text in its place instead?

I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: How you change the text to "blue" if user selects blue is the way to change the text to "red" if user selects "red" later.

Comment: Yes I know that but it just compounds onto the previously displayed text. How do I make sure it erases the previous text and displays the new text in its place? So if the user clicks around multiple options on the menu, there's not a long line of text from every time they made a selection?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which shows how you are changing the color.

Comment: we'd need to see a [mcve] to help with that

Comment: You should create the output text once and update its text based on user selection.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, I think I figured it out though. As I was producing a simplified example it seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should create the result label once and set `textvariable` option to the same as the tkinter variable used for those radiobuttons.  Then every time you select one of the radiobuttons, the result label will be updated.

Below is a simple example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x100")

menubar = tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)

menu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
var1 = tk.StringVar()
for color in ("blue", "red", "yellow"):
    menu.add_radiobutton(label=color, variable=var1, value=color)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Color", menu=menu)

tk.Label(root, textvariable=var1, font="Arial 32 bold", width=10).pack()

root.mainloop()
```